# Remove marker from folium map

Tags: python, folium

With the following code I am able to add marker to the folium maps:

```
import folium
import time

m = folium.Map(location = [13.0, 77.0], tiles=None, zoom_start = 5, control_scale = True)

img_path = 'Path to Image File'

folium.Marker(location=[0, 0], icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image=img_path, icon_size=(25, 25))).add_to(m)

time.sleep(5)
```

Now I want to remove this marker from the map after `time.sleep(5)`. How can I achieve this.

Comment: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1233

Comment: Thanks @user2856.